# Drag the VPageBreaks all the way to the right but nothing is happening

Tags: excel, vba

```
Application.ActiveWindow.View = xlPageBreakPreview

Set Workbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Workbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, "A").Value = "CTY" Then
            Workbook.Sheets(1).Rows(i + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
    End If
Next i

Application.ActiveSheet.VPageBreaks(1).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
Application.ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

This code iss adding page breaks in loop to every row and then is supposed to drag the vertical page break all the way to the right but im getting an object not defined error.

Comment: @BigBen wbkCurBook is Workbook. i think the error is coming from the loop even though it adds the page break to all the necessary rows it just doesnt move the vertical ones

Comment: @BigBen i JUST  edited to include the set and it doesnt work with it either. AThe code breaks in the loop, but the loop does everything i want it to, just not the last two lines of code at the end outside of the loop

Comment: @BigBen is  an object

Comment: @BigBen oh i forgot to change Set wbkCurBook to Workbook. I was just doing minimal reproducible example